# removing an object from array of objects using object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in my javascript application, looks something like

```
var data = [
 {
  id:2467,
  name:'alex',
  grade:'B',
 },
 {
  id:5236,
  name:'bob',
  grade:'A-',
 },
 {
  id:1784,
  name:'carl',
  grade:'C',
 },
 {
  id:5841,
  name:'dave',
  grade:'AA',
 },
 {
  id:3278,
  name:'harry',
  grade:'B+',
 },
]
```

Now I have to remove or pop an object from this array on the basis of object id, using a function something like

```
function removeStudent(id){
  //logic for removing object based on object id
}
```

It should be like

```
removeStudent(5236);
```

then the data array afterwards should be like

```
var data = [
 {
  id:2467,
  name:'alex',
  grade:'B',
 },
 {
  id:1784,
  name:'carl',
  grade:'C',
 },
 {
  id:5841,
  name:'dave',
  grade:'AA',
 },
 {
  id:3278,
  name:'harry',
  grade:'B+',
 },
]
```

I tried using `pop()` but I think that will remove the last element from the array, not the specific one.
I have looked at this post of removing an element from array

[How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

but I didn't find my answer here respected to objects
Needed help!

Comment: I'm amazed by the 10k+ users who are answering an obvious duplicate :)

Comment: Or if you whish, you can use a wonderful library like `lodash`, and use Arrays methods (dropXXX, pullXXX) : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pullAllBy

Comment: @Adelin yes I really agree with you they could just comment and then mark it as dup.

Comment: @OP: *I didn't find my answer here respected to objects*. And in case you'll need to filter by `name` you'll post another question as well?

Comment: @Adelin First of all I am fresher, recently started my developer's journey.I have been working till now in backend technologies like Servlets, Spring boot etc. Now my company wants me to work as full stack. So new in javascript.

Comment: @YashJain that doesn't justify lack of efforts and searching yourself.

Comment: @Adelin you are right but I tried to find out the answer in the post you used to mark my question as duplicate. Javascript objects are bit different than normal java object. Its easy for me to work with java objects, I am new with javascript and still I have to work over angular, jquery, typescript etc.

Comment: @Adelin anyway, thanks for letting me know that I didn't take efforts to figure out my answer. Next time, it wont be repeated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter):

```
function removeStudent(data, id) {
  return data.filter(student => student.id !== id);
}
```

It will create a **copy** of the input `data` array.

```
const newData = removeStudent(data, 5236);
```

Comment: Just a note, this will not remove the entry from the original `data`. OP would have to use `data = removeStudent(data, id)`

Comment: @Phil Yup, worth to mention - added in my answer.

Comment: Or just use `splice` method in combination with `findIndex` like in my answer.

Comment: `Array.filter` iterates till the end of the array even though the match is found at the first index. It effects performance. What do you think?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal doesn't `array.splice` also have a complexity of `O(n)`? So would that really matter if the `filter` looks more elegant.

Comment: @vibhor1997a - Makes sense. I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var data = [ { id:2467, name:'alex', grade:'B', }, { id:5236, name:'bob', grade:'A-', }, { id:1784, name:'carl', grade:'C', }, { id:5841, name:'dave', grade:'AA', }, { id:3278, name:'harry', grade:'B+', }];

function removeStudent(_id){
  var index = data.findIndex(({id}) => id === _id);
  if(index !== -1) data.splice(index,1);
}
removeStudent(5236);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array filter method. It will return a new array of matched elements.In your case you need to return all the objects where id is not the the one which is passed in argument

```js
var data = [{
    id: 2467,
    name: 'alex',
    grade: 'B',
  },
  {
    id: 5236,
    name: 'bob',
    grade: 'A-',
  },
  {
    id: 1784,
    name: 'carl',
    grade: 'C',
  },
  {
    id: 5841,
    name: 'dave',
    grade: 'AA',
  },
  {
    id: 3278,
    name: 'harry',
    grade: 'B+',
  },
]

function removeStudent(id) {
  return data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id !== id;
  })
}
console.log(removeStudent(5236));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `findIndex` instead, by passing a `callback` function as *argument*

```js
var data = [ { id:2467, name:'alex', grade:'B', }, { id:5236, name:'bob', grade:'A-', }, { id:1784, name:'carl', grade:'C', }, { id:5841, name:'dave', grade:'AA', }, { id:3278, name:'harry', grade:'B+', }, ]
let id = 5236;
data.splice(data.findIndex(p => p.id == id), 1);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` but make sure you reassign the filter result to `data` to overwrite the original value:

```js
var data = [
 {
  id:2467,
  name:'alex',
  grade:'B',
 },
 {
  id:5236,
  name:'bob',
  grade:'A-',
 },
 {
  id:1784,
  name:'carl',
  grade:'C',
 },
 {
  id:5841,
  name:'dave',
  grade:'AA',
 },
 {
  id:3278,
  name:'harry',
  grade:'B+',
 },
];

function removeStudent(data, id){
  return data.filter(student => student.id !== id);
}

data = removeStudent(data, 5236);
console.log(data);
```